# How to unclude a unique attribute in a GROUP BY statement

Tags: sql, oracle18c

How to include a unique attribute in a GROUP BY statement.
For example we have the following tables:

MPD

| MPD_ID | DUMMY_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 |
| 1 | 44 |
| 2 | 22 |
| 2 | 33 |

DUMMY

| DUMMY_ID | NUMBER_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 1 |
| 22 | 2 |
| 33 | 2 |
| 44 | 1 |

NUMBER

| NUMBER_ID | NUMBER |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |

```
SELECT nr.number, dm.id FROM MPD mpd
JOIN dummy dm on mpd.dummy_id = dm.dummy_id
JOIN number nr on dm.number_id = nr.number_id
WHERE nr.number > 4
GROUP BY nr.number, dm.id
HAVING COUNT(nr.number) > 1;
```

The search must be based on the parent object MPD. So we want to find the "duplicate" DUMMY entries based on the MPD they are connected with.

The above selection would return 0 results because the , `dm.dummy_id` is not the same for all entries, thus it wouldn't pass by from the GROUP BY as GROUP BY needs all attributes per entry to be equal in order to group them.

If the `dm.dummy_id` would be removed then the query would work as it should and it would return DUMMY_IDs 11 and 44 because their respective dm.id are equal. But the basic information about the ids of the entries to be found would be missing.

How can I use group by and having count to identify my duplicate entries, but return the dm.dummy_id in the select statement?

Is there maybe a way maybe to include an attribute in the GROUP BY but not to be taken in mind within the GROUP BY?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by nr) as cnt_nr
      from dummy t
     ) t
where cnt_nr > 1;
```

Comment: I am not sure how to implement this into the logic of my query. My main problem is that my information is spread in 3 tables, thus I have to use joins for those. And eventually the information I want to connect is in different tables, and the entries must also be grouped based on a secondary value.

Comment: @Sir.Hedgehog . . . This answers the question you have asked here, which references only one table.  If you have a different question, ask it as a *new* question.  This question has been answered.

Comment: The question has been answered, but the question as it seems was not complete. I have edited the question, and it is at your disposal if you want to take a look at it again. I appreciate your answer anyhow.